# SQL Server INSERTED table to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers

I created these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE public.articulos 
( id integer PRIMARY KEY,
nombre varchar(100),
stock decimal(18,2));

CREATE TABLE public.movimientos
( transaccion integer,
fecha date DEFAULT current_date,
articulo_id integer, 
cantidad decimal(10,2),
tipo char(1) CHECK (tipo='E' OR tipo='S'),
FOREIGN KEY (articulo_id) REFERENCES public.articulos(id));
```

I am trying to adapt the code from :
[image: SQL Server Trigger]

To PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE FUNCTION inserta() RETURNS trigger AS $actualiza$
    BEGIN
        -- Actualizamos la fecha
        UPDATE public.articulos 
        SET stock=stock + T.parcial
        FROM public.articulos A
        INNER JOIN
        (SELECT articulo_id,
         SUM(CASE WHEN tipo='E' 
             THEN cantidad
             ELSE -cantidad 
         END)
    AS parcial FROM movimientos
    GROUP BY articulo_id
    )
    T ON A.id=T.articulo_id;
    RETURN NULL;
    END;
$actualiza$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER movimientosinsert
AFTER INSERT
ON public.movimientos
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE inserta();
```

What I still don't get is how these two lines from SQL Server:

```
AS parcial FROM INSERTED
SET stock=stock + T.parcial
```

So that when I run something like:

```
INSERT INTO public.movimientos (transaccion,articulo_id,fecha,cantidad,tipo)
VALUES (1,1,current_date,100,'E'),
(2,2,current_date,25,'S');
```

The trigger calls the function and the function does its work.

Any help with be really thanked because I have looked up for the solution but I have just found that the words `New` & `Old` could help if referring to specific column.
But what if I want to refer to the all the columns from a specific table then?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need that in Postgres - at least not when using a row level trigger (which you do, because you have `for each row`). Just use the `new` and `old` records available in the trigger: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html

Comment: Could you help me with some more information @a_horse_with_no_name? I have used the `new`, `old` but I do not know how to implement them in Postgres to refer to all the columns from the table

Comment: Just like any column reference. `new.column_name`. Do read the manual it contains a lot of examples. Remember that you always deal with exactly **one** row in a row level trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this I would say:

```
CREATE FUNCTION inserta() RETURNS trigger AS $actualiza$
BEGIN
  -- Actualizamos la fecha
  UPDATE public.articulos 
    SET stock = stock + case 
                          when new.tipo = 'E' then new.cantidad  
                          else -new.cantidad 
                        end
  where articulos.articulo_id = new.articulo_id;

  RETURN null;
END;
$actualiza$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

As you are using a row level trigger (something SQL Server does not have), you will always deal with exactly one row, so there is no need to use `group by` (although it's been ages that I used SQL Server - maybe I'm misunderstanding something in the original trigger).

Comment: Thanks for your quick and descriptive answer!